# sum in excel until value met and show column header

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Hi and thank you in advance.

I want to sum up columns I2 to U2 but when the amount of the sum reaches 15, I want cell Y2 to display the column header, that are held in I1 to U1.

[image]

Comment: Please show some exanple outcome. What header so you want to display, all values of I2 to U2 in one cell, or the cell that makes the sum exceed 15?

Comment: I want the Cell that makes the sum exceed 15, or specifically the header of that cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should provide a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

If I got it right, it should display the month (header) upon the sum reaches 15.
That can be achieved with the following formula:

```
=IF(SUM(A1)>=15, A1, IF(SUM(A2:B2)>=15, B1, IF(SUM(A2:C2)>=15, C1, IF(SUM(A2:D2)>=15, D1, IF(...)
```

Obviously you'll have to change it to whatever length required. Perhaps not the most elegant of solutions, but it gets the job done.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, will do that next time!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following formula, which needs to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=INDEX($I$1:$U$1,MATCH(TRUE,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(I2:U2,0,0,1,COLUMN(I2:U2)-COLUMN(I2)+1))>=Y$1,0))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, think this has worked!